# Django save field

Tags: python, django, view

im currently trying to save a field (pubpgp) with a none vaule if the user does not provide any information on that (it's optional).
But for some reason i'm not able to save the actuall form without providing the information for the field "pubpgp"...
how to solve this?

```
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        try:
            pubpgp = PGPKey.from_blob(request.POST['pubpgp'].rstrip("\r\n"))[0]
        except:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO,"PGP-Key is wrong formated.")
            return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
        if pubpgp.key_algorithm == PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncryptOrSign:
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "Profile has been updated successfully.")
            return redirect(reverse('home'))
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "PGP-Key is wrong formated.")
            return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        args = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'edit_profile.html', args)
```

models.py

```
pubpgp = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=3000, unique=True)
```

Comment: What error message did you get? Isn't this caused by `unique=True`?

Comment: i simply get. PGP-Key is wrong formated.

Comment: And sadly its not about the unique flag

Comment: If `request.POST['pubpgp']` values is `None`, you will get error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rstrip'`. Try to comment out for some time try/except clause and see what errors you will get then.